# Running command in UserData as a not-root user

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, user-data

I am trying to install airflow using an EC2 UserData script. I need to run some commands using a not-root user (ec2-user).
See the script below:

```
  UserData:
    Fn::Base64: !Sub |
      #!/bin/bash
      set -xe
      # Install GCC
      yum install -y gcc
      # Install Dependencies
      pip install boto3 awscli markupsafe six


      export AIRFLOW_GPL_UNIDECODE=yes
      export AIRFLOW_HOME=/home/ec2-user/airflow
      pip install apache-airflow[crypto,postgres]


      su - ec2-user
      whoami
      PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
      airflow initdb
```

I just investigated the log and it seems that the command `su - ec2-user` is not working a `whoami` is returning `root user.`

```
+ su - ec2-user
Last login: Sat Aug 10 15:59:37 UTC 2019 from ip-10-1-13-234.us-west-2.compute.internal on pts/0
+ whoami
root
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use **sudo -u** to run a single command as a non-root user.

`sudo -u ec2-user whoami`

You can also start a subshell if you want to run multiple commands.

`sudo -u ec2-user bash -c 'whoami;PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin;airflow initdb'`

Answer (score 10):

For who is searching how to run user-data as ec2-user, the easiest solution I found was using *sudo* `-u` and `-i` options:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
sudo -u ec2-user -i <<'EOF'

cmd1
cmd2
cmd3

EOF
```